# React Multiple Loading state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a loading icon for each card while the data is fetching from the API. Is there another way to keep this DRY? ... to avoid repeating myself?

```
{isLoading ? (<Loader />) : (
    <div className="module card">{sales_numbers}</div>
)}

{isLoading ? (<Loader />) : (
    <div className="module card">{accounts_numbers}</div>
)}

{isLoading ? (<Loader />) : (
    <div className="module card">{users_numbers}</div>
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with an array your data and calling `.map()` for displaying values. You can store those items in [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook for function component or `this.state` in a class component.

Try the following if you have a function component:

```
const [values] = useState([sales_numbers, account_numbers, users_numbers]);

return <>
    {
        values.map(e => isLoading ?
                        <Loader /> :
                        <div className="module card">{e}</div>
        )
    }
</>
```

In class component you need to store within `this.state` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        values: [sales_numbers, account_numbers, users_numbers]
    }
}

render() {
    return <>
        {
            this.state.values.map(e => isLoading ?
                                       <Loader /> :
                                       <div className="module card">{e}</div>
            )
        }
    </>
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try building a component that manage loading state by itself.
This way you can have something like

```
export default ({data}) => (
   data ? <div className="module card">{data}</div> : <Loader />
)
```

Your only concern is to pass data prop for each entity.